# Is Android Context thread safe?

Tags: android

When I use the Android Context within an AsyncTask#doInBackground, is it thread safe? The context is provided via constructor or via getApplicationContext() from a surrounding Activity. This simple questions is asked a lot at stackoverflow and else where but I found not a clear answer?

E.g. in the doInBackground() I use the context in order to Instantiate an DAO class.

```
 @Override
 protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {  

   ExampleDao dao = new ExampleDao(context);
   ...

 }
```

I saw several examples doing that in this way, but I cannot image that this is thread-safe, because the context is now accessed by the main tread (UI Thread) and the worker thread.

Comment: Can you please calrify a bit more, what exactly you are doing?

Comment: Why should't that be thread safe? The worker thread uses the context to access the file system and the UI Thread uses the context for all the UI related stuff. There shouldn't be a problem with mixed calls that access the same resource etc.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can always access the context from different Thread as long as you are not changing something and you only retrieve resources through the context I don't see a problem with Thread-safety.

The problem is that the context will stay in memory and active as long as the Thread runs. This is a good thing for you because you can rely on having a valid context all the time. 
The bad thing is that if you pass an Activity as a context all the views and member variables from this activity will also stay in memory and this can lead to a very late garbage collection for a lot of memory, like Waqas suggested.

On thing I would not do from a different Thread is accessing methods from Context subclasses like [setTheme()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ContextThemeWrapper.html#setTheme%28int%29) that will affect the currently displayed views.

Comment: Sounds good, thus you would prefere to use getApplicationContext() instead of passing the whole activity to the AsyncTask?

Comment: Yes passing down the application context will never do you any harm and protect you from strange memory problems, that are hard to find in java.

Answer (score 2):

If you dont need to do anything with **Views** then always try to use `getApplicationContext()` which refers to application's context (not activity's context) and may help you to avoid memory leaks while threading or orientation-changes. So, i guess it fits for your needs in AsyncTask too.

Comment: This means that I can access the context indepent from the UI Thread in the worker thread?

Answer (score 1):

Context is not threadsafe actually. But it is ok to pass an instance of application context to write to db for example.

Comment: just for my own knowledge, can you explain "Context is not threadsafe" a little more? i mean, why it isn't?

Comment: I mean to access the Context from two different threads, in my example from the UI Thread and from the worker thread.

Comment: It is not thread safe in the meaning of making synchronization for write-reading operations, as there are no any. But since you don't write anything, it is usable from different threads.