# Concerns with passing Activity as a method parameter

Tags: java, android

Are there any performance (or other) concerns on passing Activity as a method parameter? I need to define an image picker/cropper in a modular way (UtilClass) that can be used in several activities and I will need to make Activity-dependent calls.

Comment: You need to consider memory leaks

Comment: That is no problem, you just need to do Garbage Collection yourself

Answer (score 1):

Well there is no performance concern, since you will pass the memory address.

Take a look at this post please:
[Is Android Context thread safe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10598864/is-android-context-thread-safe)

Answer (score 1):

You should avoid keeping reference to activity after it closed, I see two ways: using WeakReference in Utility class or set activity reference to null in Utility class in onDestroy \ onPause method.