# Are Contexts and System Services thread safe?

Tags: java, android, thread-safety, android-context

**Background:** I am creating a few background jobs that run in a thread pool (i.e. the jobs are running concurrently and not on the main/UI thread). The jobs interact with a context or system service in one or more of the following ways:

- Get a system service (`context.getSystemService`) and uses its API

  - `NotificationManager`
  - `DevicePolicyManager`
  - etc.
- Start/stop other services (`context.startService` and `context.stopService`)
- Register broadcast receivers (`context.registerReceiver`)

**Question:** Are Contexts and System Services thread-safe? Do I have to hop onto the main thread every time I need to interact with a context and/or system service?

I have looked through the [Processes/Threads guide](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads) but nothing mentions the use of contexts or system services and I can't find anything relating to thread-safety in the [context documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context) or the documentation for the various system services.

For clarification, I am not attempting to update the user interface. I am just trying to *concurrently* use the application context and system services provided by that context.

Also, there is a [similarly titled question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10598864/is-android-context-thread-safe) on SO. However, the answer states that read-only properties of the context are thread-safe, which is not helpful; and the other answers are vague and don't point to any sources. Also also, I am **not** worried about leaking the context; I am using the application context.

Comment: Further clarification: the post [Safely using android 'Context' inside threads](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/98806/safely-using-android-context-inside-threads) is not what I am looking for. That post is concerned with leaking the context, not the thread safety of said context.

Answer (score 0):

Services retrieved using "*getSystemService()*" are closely related to current Context and it is discouraged to share/pass/keep these Services. Google's DOCs says this.

System Services are internally used via Binders, so it's thread-safe to call System Service's methods from any thread.
Warning: retrivied Objects/Classes from these thread-safe methods **could not be thread-safe!!**

Context's methods exists to provide "*Resources*" (Drawables, Colors, etc... real resources, or Display/Screen informations, etc...) and returned data is usually a deep cloned Object fully usable in thread-safe mode from inside this specific Context.
I.E: "*Context.getDisplay()*" will returns different Object (I mean the pointer in memory) in each Context you call it. But it could returns different Object at each call even in the same Context. It depends.

Starting/Stopping a Service is thread-safe because "*startService()*" is a Context's method (the reason I explained above).